# WCF REST and QueryString, wrong UriTemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, rest

Hi i have a simple WCF REST service, i need to get some parameters via querystring that looks like this.

page=1&rp=10&sortname=id&sortorder=asc&query=&qtype=Application

My UriTemplate not working, what is wrong here? just trying to get the page param so far. Any idea how the uri should look like?

```
[OperationContract]

    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "/?page={page}")]

    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
    JSONData GetLogList(string page);
```

Here is my service code

```
   public class LogService : ILog
{
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat =    System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]

    public JSONData GetLogList(string page)
    {
        var logContext = new LogViewDataContext();
        var logsList = from logs in logContext.Logs select logs;
        //return logsList.Cast<Log>().ToString();


        var baseData = new JSONData();
        baseData.page = Int32.Parse(page ?? "1");
        baseData.total = logsList.Count();

        var cells = new ArrayList();


        var tmplist = new List<JSONDataRow>();
        foreach(var log in logsList)
        {
            var row = new JSONDataRow();
            row.id = log.ID;
            cells.Add(value: log.Date);
            cells.Add(value: log.Application);
            cells.Add(value: log.Server);
            cells.Add(value: log.Message);
            row.cell = cells;

            tmplist.Add(row);

        }

        int x = Int32.Parse(page);
        int pageSize = 10;



        baseData.rows = tmplist.Skip((x - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
        return baseData;
    }

}
```

Here is the javascript that calling the service.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#logGrid").flexigrid({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://MyWeb/Services/LogService.svc/',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",


        colModel: [
            { display: 'Date', name: 'Date', width: 40, sortable: true, align: 'left' },
            { display: 'Application', name: 'Application', width: 150, sortable: true, align: 'left' },
            { display: 'Server', name: 'Server', width: 150, sortable: true, align: 'left' },
            { display: 'Message', name: 'Message', width: 250, sortable: true, align: 'left' }
        ],


        searchitems: [
            { display: 'Date', name: 'Date' },
            { display: 'Application', name: 'Application', isdefault: true },
            { display: 'Server', name: 'Server' }
        ],
        sortname: "id",
        sortorder: "asc",
        usepager: true,
        title: "test",
        useRp: true,
        rp: 10,
        showTableToggleBtn: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 700,
        height: 370,
        singleSelect: true

    });

});

       </script>
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working? What does the URL look like that you are using?

Comment: page parameter is always null in service, but the query params always has values.

Answer (score 6):

Can you set your URITemplate as follows:

```
URITemplate="/GetLogList?page={page}"
```

Then your URL from  jquery should be like:

```
http://MyWeb/Services/LogService.svc/GetLogList?page=1
```

UPDATE:

If you want the other parameters as in your query string just append them to the URItemplate

Ex:

```
URITemplate="/GetLogList?page={page}&sortorder={sortorder}"
```

And then just have your method to have that parameter

```
JSONData GetLogList(string page, string sortorder);
```

Try to inspect the complete request with [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) when making the request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i do i POST from the javascript. Is this the right way to get the parameters then?

Comment: Query strings are used when you are trying to fetch i.e. perform a GET. Also its a good practise to make sure that the operation relates to the name of the resource. You are trying to perform a POST but your resource name states a GET. If the method is just intended to retrieve some data and show to the user mark it as WebGet rather than WebInvoke

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use the first slash in the signature of the URL template? I usually go *URITemplate="Some/Thing"* and it produces the same request URL pattern.